# Use Button to Switch Bootstrap Carousel?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, carousel

I wonder if I can use a normal button to slide from one Bootstrap Carousel to another?

I can only make it the way below(which is way too ugly):

```
<!-- Controls -->
      <a class="left carousel-control btn btn-default" href="#mycarousel" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
      </a>
      <a class="right carousel-control btn btn-default" href="#mycarousel" data-slide="next">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
      </a>
```

Is there a better way of doing this? Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion or other way ( *maybe not the better way* ):

```
<a class="carousel-control left" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">&lsaquo;</a>
<a class="carousel-control right" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">&rsaquo;</a>
```

See [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Shady_Alset/1135581v/) Example. *Thanks !*